# with::after class & without ::after class css is not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have tried to add css for button, its not working.

```
<button>Test<button>
```

**CSS**

```
.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
  padding: 8px 18px;
}
.button:not(.button:after):hover,
.button:not(.button:after):focus,
.button:not(.button:after):active {
  padding: 8px 38px;
}
```

Thanks advance

Comment: You need to fix your typo on your `button` so that it is closed properly.

Comment: I'm not clear about typo, can you advise on this?

Comment: Your opening `<button>` tag needs to be closed properly. You have `<button>Test<button>`, but it should be: `<button>Test</button>`. Also, CSS pseudo-elements, like `after` should have two colons before them, not one (i.e. `::after`).

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't work like this, you can't target pseudo-elements within the `:not()` selector.

If, however, you're wanting the browser to ignore when a user hovers their cursor over a pseudo-element which itself isn't overlapping the element itself, you can do this with the `pointer-events` property like so:

```css
button {
  position: relative;
}

button:hover,
button:focus {
  color: red;
}

button::after {
  content: 'Pseudo-element';
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 150%;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}

button:hover::after,
button:focus::after {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" autofocus>
  Button
</button>
```

Comment: I recommend color: currentcolor over color: initial. The initial value of color may not necessarily be currentcolor; it is usually the default font color as set by the user or the platform's theme settings.

Comment: @BoltClock what's amazing is that I've never seen this `currentColor` property before, and it looks like it works back to IE9?! I've clearly been living under a rock. **Edit:** applying this to the snippet causes it to inherit the red hover colour, is that because it doesn't fall through to anything else?

Comment: Hm, I see why you went with initial now. The idea was to avoid coloring the generated content on hover, right? If so, currentcolor won't be of help here, since as you pointed out, the color is being inherited from the button on hover.

Comment: @BoltClock, my question is different, if the button has ::after, I want to add few CSS properties incase  the button does not have ::after it should react certain CSS properties. In my case I have multiple buttons with icon and icon background, if the button has icon, ::after class will added by CSS incase  its  button does not have ::after class. Actually those things are working fine for me. I want to add one more condition over the button after. I already tried to implement using :not in CSS but it is not working.